# React - Passing props to child onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an index of images and titles I am pulling in from Dropbox. I aim to be able to click on a title and load a specific project, but right now I'm simply trying to get to grips with passing the data of a clicked title to the a component.

I've looked at the React tutorial, the documentation & other similar questions on here (& am concerned this will be treated as a duplicate question), but I can't seem to figure out a way of passing the specific title that is clicked. I'm currently getting the error: *Cannot read property 'title' of undefined*.

I've managed to pull out the specific title via console.log & filled the ProjectTitle component with all of the titles but am stumped at this seemingly simple hurdle.

Thanks

```
class ProjectTitle extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>;
    }
}

class Index extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            imageSource: [],
            imageTitles: [],
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        …
    }

    render(){
        if(!this.state.imageSource.length)
            return null;
        let titles = this.state.imageTitles.map((el, i) => <p>{el}</p>)
        let images = this.state.imageSource.map((el, i) =>

        <div className="imageContainer">
            <img key={i} className='images' src={el}/>
            <div className="imageTitle" onClick={() => 
                ProjectTitle.props.title(titles[i].props.children)}>{titles[i]}
            </div>
        </div>
        )

        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                {images}
                <ProjectTitle />
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add new `title` to `state` and then update that title `onclick`. The pass the `state.title` as props for `ProjectTitle`

Comment: You sure that `imageSources` has the same length as `imageTitles`?

Comment: Tareq's comment makes sense, and you might want to do some ternary checking if the activeTitle is set, then render the component, else render undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally in a situation like this, you want to follow this structure:

1. Click event handler sets a state property like `activeTitle` to the id that was clicked.
2. The element whose prop needs to be set (`ProjectTitle`) gets it from it's parent state (`Index`).

The changes to your code might look something like:

```
// in Index constructor 
this.state = {
    // stuff you already have...
    activeTitle: null
}
this.handleItemClick = this.handleItemClick.bind(this);

// in Index
handleItemClick(title) {
    this.setState({activeTitle: title});
}

// in Index.render() in the loop
// you might have you add some code to get titles[i]
<div className="imageTitle" onClick={() => this.handleItemClick(titles[i])}></div>

// in Index.render() return statement
<ProjectTitle title={this.state.activeTitle} />
```